# Notepad++ RTL with LTR text in same line

Tags: right-to-left, arabic-support

I am doing Langauge translarion for Website  Community.ini file

I have test in english with some codes which is from website
-shared %1$s photo(s)    { I just want to translate Shared & Photos in arabic but %s makes a problem, How we can write both RTL and LTR in same line.I have Notepad++ editor.

but results is comming like  المشتركة %1$s photo(s)